# reCaptcha code not rendered with EWZRecaptchaBundle if template is called trough AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, recaptcha

I'm having this weird issue and I can't find a way to get it down so I need your help. I have downloaded, installed and configured EWZRecaptchaBundle and all, apparently, is fine. This is how my `config.yml` section for the bundle is:

```
#EWZRecaptchaBundle
ewz_recaptcha:
    public_key:   "%recaptcha_public_key%"
    private_key:  "%recaptcha_public_key%"
    locale_key:   %kernel.default_locale%
    enabled: true
```

The key are setup correctly since I can see this [URL](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6Le0gvgSAAAAAA9TcipaADEplRG2mU_dk4S8uiaz) on the browser and this is how I added the field to my form:

```
$builder
    ->add('captcha', 'ewz_recaptcha', array(
        'mapped' => FALSE,
        'attr' => array(
            'options' => array(
                'theme' => 'clean'
            )
        ),
        'constraints' => array(
            new True()
        )
    ))
 ....
```

I also added the use statement for the validation:

```
use EWZ\Bundle\RecaptchaBundle\Validator\Constraints\True;
```

And this is the result on the Twig template after render the field:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var RecaptchaOptions = {"theme":"clean"}
</script>
<script src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6Le0gvgSAAAAAA9TcipaADEplRG2mU_dk4S8uiaz" type="text/javascript"></script>
<noscript>
    "<iframe src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6Le0gvgSAAAAAA9TcipaADEplRG2mU_dk4S8uiaz" height="300" width="500"></iframe>
    <br/>
    <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"&gt;&lt;/textarea&gt;&lt;input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/>
    "
</noscript>
```

Why the `"` in the `<noscript>` tags? Why the `<noscript>` tags? Why the image is not rendered? Any advice or help on this? I'm getting crazy and can't find any solution

Comment: Is there anything in your Js log?

Comment: @Maerlyn yes, this message `Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.` I forgot to add to the main post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Displaying a reCAPTCHA via an AJAX request requires special handling.

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#AJAX

Comment: Is not the reCaptcha what I load trough AJAX is the Twig template where the reCaptcha is rendered

Comment: @ReynierPM A semantic difference that changes absolutely nothing. You will need to implement the approach I linked to.

Comment: As mentioned by @ceejayoz the repatcha needs a special handling if you want to init the library though AJAX. The error message you specify is a well known issue with AJAX library loading... IMO, you should report this limitation to the maintainer of the bundle as it is clearly not supported currently. Meanwhile, you will need to implement your own solution...

Comment: @egeloen I was doing some research and it's implemented ([see here](https://github.com/excelwebzone/EWZRecaptchaBundle/blob/master/Form/Type/RecaptchaType.php)) but I can't find how to enable the AJAX Url at config level or if I need to do some else in my Form definitiion, any advice?

Comment: @ReynierPM I believe that's just a part of the reCAPTCHA library's code. It doesn't appear to actually be implemented beyond that line. https://github.com/excelwebzone/EWZRecaptchaBundle/issues/15 https://github.com/excelwebzone/EWZRecaptchaBundle/issues/22

Comment: Any idea in how to implement this feature? I'm not an expert so have my toughs on this, just need some guide from yours in order to get this fixed. I think to change to GenemuFormBundle but it has a lot of useless things so I'll remain on this one (has two months without support from developer and this is weird)